# Which color to chose for the dba.exchange site?

Tags: discussion

I talk about the color that is used as background for questions matching interesting tag.

SO uses well I don't know its between red and brown
SU uses a kind of blue
SF uses some light red

I mention these sites, because there you find sql related questions too.

What about some light green (decent as in SF)?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that we need to worry about that -- as we're getting ready to move out of beta, we'll get some assistance from Jin, their graphic designer.  It's easier to let him come up with a design and then critique it rather than just start suggesting colors randomly.

Of course, for him to come up with a design, there's the whole issue of coming up with a name that fits, so he can then use that for inspiration.

You can see some of his designs if you visit the other [stackexchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites).

Comment: Actually this question fits with one of the [7 Essential Meta Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) - "What should our logo and site design look like?"

Comment: @BenV : design is related to color, but 'post preliminary (or finished) designs' doesn't typically mean 'pick what colors we should use'.  If that's all it took to make a good design, we wouldn't have had GeoCities to make fun of.  (and as someone who used to have to do webdesign, I want to stab anyone who comes in with the 'but could you make the stuff on the left green?' ... especially as this was before the days of CSS, so changing colors was a crapshoot of regex replacement if that same color was in more than one place)