# Can the color scheme for similar questions be changed?

Tags: feature-request, design

Can the orange on yellow color scheme for matching/similar questions be changed.
The contrast between the two colors is low.
I see a similar question [Which color to chose for the dba.exchange site?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98/which-color-to-chose-for-the-dba-exchange-site) asked over 2 years ago.
The image shown uses the color scheme I am referring to.

[image: Color Scheme]

And the scheme for `Questions that may already have your answer` on this meta page is not much better.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot?  I'm not entirely clear about what you are asking about.  Also could you explain what's wrong with the current color scheme?